zsh completion : don't complete if ambiguous, only show menu
I would like to configure zsh completion so that, whenver there remains some ambiguity, the completion stops at ambiguity, so that I can type the next few characters (as an alternative to browsing the menu).
Example:
$export TTAB
currently gives
$export TERM=
TERM                 TIMEFMT              TMPPREFIX          
TRY_BLOCK_ERROR      TRY_BLOCK_INTERRUPT  TTY                
TTYIDLE          

As a result, if I was looking e.g. for TRY_BLOCK_ERROR, I have to use the menu.
Rather, I'd like the prompt to have remained export T since there is ambiguity, and if I type on character R, I would like to have:
$export TRTAB
$export TRY_BLOCK_      
TRY_BLOCK_ERROR      TRY_BLOCK_INTERRUPT

so completing only to TRY_BLOCK_, since it is ambiguous beyong that.
I have read a couple tutos about zsh completion but it's difficult for me to spot which keywords are associated to this sort of behaviour.

I have found these settings to match my expectations:
zstyle ':completion:*' insert-unambiguous true
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=1 interactive
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s

